# Extracting data from the link and placing it in a new column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have several links:

```
    Column1                                    Column2           
    ---------------
   <a href=" https://link; m=date1>Link</a>     date1        
   <a href=" https://link; m=date2>Link</a>     date2
   <a href=" https://link; m=date3>Link</a>     date3
```

The resultant column should look like:

```
    Column1                                    Column2       Column3     
    ---------------
   <a href=" https://link; m=date1>Link</a>     date1         date1  
   <a href=" https://link; m=date2>Link</a>     date2         date2
   <a href=" https://link; m=date3>Link</a>     date3         date3
```

I would like to extract from the link (date1, date2, date3) and those values add to Column3 coincide with the values in column2.

What query should I use because I have no idea?

Comment: Fix the table formatting so we can understand what data belongs to each column. And also specify the expected result.

Comment: I agree with jarlh. You have three column headers, but I can only identify two different columns. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. Also: did you mean `date1` instead of `data2` in your question?

Comment: ok, I edited this and now should look better

Comment: what the condition is needed to extract them, and why are you multiplexing the same data..? A better way might be produce `1` if value of `column2` exists within `column1`, else `0` as the value for `column3`.

Comment: Looks like you just want a copy of Column2?

Comment: I want extract date1 , date2, date3 from Column1 to Column3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
select col1, col2, case when regexp_like(col1,col2) then col2 end as col3  
  from t
```

just to check out column col2's value exists within col1, and generate col3

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c66ae0b8f47c7f0606b623ab9607356f)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Barbaros Özhan :D